# .update in model - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

In my order model, I have the callback below. Everything works fine until the last line, where I try to update 1 invoice attribute and trigger an after_update callback in the invoice model but I receive a wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) when I use the .update() method.

```
def update_invoice # self = order
...
  invoice = Invoice.find_or_create_by(job_id: job.id, start_string: start_string, end_string: end_string, client_id: client.id, start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date)
  self.update_column(:invoice_id, invoice.id)
  statement_start_date = start_date.beginning_of_month
  statement_end_date = end_date.end_of_month
  statement = Statement.find_or_create_by(start_date: statement_start_date, end_date: statement_end_date, client_id: client.id)
  self.update_column(:statement_id, statement.id)
  invoice.update(statement_id: statement.id) # wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) error
end
```

The below works as a work around:

```
invoice.update_column(:statement_id, statement.id)
invoice.save
```

Why does the first method not work like I expected it to?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update is a class method. this should work:

```
Invoice.update(invoice.id, :statement_id => statement.id)
```

also you could use update_attribute

```
invoice.update_attribute('statement_id', statement.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I've used the same syntax (update on a variable, not the class) in my app and it worked.  Any idea why that would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

[update](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) method is available only at class level.

Use either

```
invoice.update_attribute(:statement_id, statement_id) #validations will be skipped
```

or

```
invoice.update_attribute(:statement_id => statement_id)
```

Do not use `update_column` since `validations` and `callbacks` will be skipped when updating using `update_column`